# Timestamp Difference In minutes for PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, time, date-arithmetic

I have the following query:

```
Select works.id, works.client_id, COALESCE(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,works.begin_at,works.finish_at), 0) / 60 * (clients.worker_cost_hourly * works.number_of_workers + works.machines *             clients.machine_cost_hourly) as cost
from works join clients on works.client_id = clients.id
where works.paid = 0
```

That works fine for `mysql` but `postgresql` is complaining about the `TIMESTAMPDIFF`... are there ways to achieve this behaviour in both DBMS with the same query?

Btw, `works.begin_at` and `works.finish_at` are defined as `time`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just substract the two times: this gives you an interval, which you can turn to seconds with `extract()`, and then to minutes using arithmetics:

```
extract(epoch from works.finish_at - works.begin_at) / 60
```

This returns an integer value. If you want the decimal part as well, then:

```
extract(epoch from works.finish_at - works.begin_at) / 60.0
```

Comment: no mysql and postgre are too different, this is by design, so that a switch will get very time and cost intensive, so that you will think twice r more if you want to switch

Comment: @Berto99: date functions are highly vendor-specific. This is Postgres syntax, it won't work in MySQL. I don't think there is a way to phrase this that would work in both databases.

Answer (score 1):

EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM works.begin_at) - EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM works.finish_at))/3600 gives you the hours difference

```
Select works.id, works.client_id
, COALESCE(T(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM works.begin_at) - EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM works.finish_at))/3600, 0) / 60 * (clients.worker_cost_hourly * works.number_of_workers 
+ works.machines * clients.machine_cost_hourly) as cost
from works join clients on works.client_id = clients.id
where works.paid = 0
```